# Solar System Mapping, ODE45 trouble

Tags: function, matlab, system

The following code aims to map out the solar system by incorporating every significant body's effect on the others.  Of course it should result in expected orbits.  In the final embedded function `GravityDE` it cannot read the values from `PlanetVec` and, because of that, cannot produce the correct new results each time. We get the error

```
??? Undefined function 'GravityDE' for input arguments of type double.
```

Any suggestions for how to solve this would be most welcome!

```
function Gravity1()

clear;
format long eng;
load('solar_system_data.mat');

StartTime = 0;
TimeStep = 24 * 3600 * 10;
EndTime = 24 * 3600 * 100;


TVec = StartTime:TimeStep:EndTime;
TimeStepMin = StartTime:2:TimeStep;

%Column Vectors for initial conditions
SunVec = [xposition(1), yposition(1), vx(1), vy(1),mass(1),1];
MercuryVec = [xposition(2), yposition(2), vx(2), vy(2),mass(2),2];
VenusVec = [xposition(3), yposition(3), vx(3), vy(3),mass(3),3];
EarthVec = [xposition(4), yposition(4),vx(4), vy(4),mass(4),4];
MoonVec = [xposition(10), yposition(10), vx(10), vy(10),mass(10),10];
MarsVec = [xposition(5), yposition(5), vx(5), vy(5),mass(5),5];
JupiterVec = [xposition(6), yposition(6), vx(6), vy(6),mass(6),6];
SaturnVec = [xposition(7), yposition(7), vx(7), vy(7),mass(7),7];
UranusVec = [xposition(8), yposition(8), vx(8), vy(8),mass(8),8];
NeptuneVec = [xposition(9), yposition(9), vx(9), vy(9),mass(9),9];
PlanetVec=[SunVec(1),SunVec(2),SunVec(3),SunVec(4),SunVec(5),SunVec(6);MercuryVec(1),       MercuryVec(2), MercuryVec(3), MercuryVec(4),MercuryVec(5),MercuryVec(6);VenusVec(1), VenusVec(2), VenusVec(3), VenusVec(4),VenusVec(5),VenusVec(6);EarthVec(1), EarthVec(2), EarthVec(3), EarthVec(4),EarthVec(5),EarthVec(6);MoonVec(1),MoonVec(2),MoonVec(3),MoonVec(4),MoonVec(5),MoonVec(6);MarsVec(1), MarsVec(2), MarsVec(3), MarsVec(4),MarsVec(5),MarsVec(6);JupiterVec(1), JupiterVec(2), JupiterVec(3), JupiterVec(4),JupiterVec(5),JupiterVec(6);SaturnVec(1), SaturnVec(2), SaturnVec(3), SaturnVec(4),SaturnVec(5),SaturnVec(6);UranusVec(1), UranusVec(2),UranusVec(3), UranusVec(4),UranusVec(5),UranusVec(6);NeptuneVec(1),       NeptuneVec(2), NeptuneVec(3), NeptuneVec(4),NeptuneVec(5),NeptuneVec(6)];
n=0;
while n<EndTime;
%Built in solver
[TimeVec, SunMat] = ode45(@GravityDE, TimeStepMin, SunVec);
[TimeVec, MercuryMat] = ode45(@GravityDE, TimeStepMin, MercuryVec);
[TimeVec, VenusMat] = ode45(@GravityDE, TimeStepMin, VenusVec);
[TimeVec, EarthMat] = ode45(@GravityDE, TimeStepMin, EarthVec);
[TimeVec, MoonMat] = ode45(@GravityDE, TimeStepMin, MoonVec);
[TimeVec,  MarsMat] = ode45(@GravityDE, TimeStepMin, MarsVec);
[TimeVec, JupiterMat] = ode45(@GravityDE, TimeStepMin, JupiterVec);
[TimeVec, SaturnMat] = ode45(@GravityDE, TimeStepMin, SaturnVec);
[TimeVec,  UranusMat] = ode45(@GravityDE, TimeStepMin, UranusVec);
[TimeVec, NeptuneMat] = ode45(@GravityDE, TimeStepMin, NeptuneVec);

SunXVec = SunMat (end,1);
SunYVec = SunMat (end,2);
SunVXVec = SunMat(end,3);
SunVYVec = SunMat(end,4);

MercuryXVec = MercuryMat (end,1);
MercuryYVec = MercuryMat (end,2);
MercuryVXVec = MercuryMat(end,3);
MercuryVYVec = MercuryMat(end,4);

VenusXVec = VenusMat (end,1);
VenusYVec = VenusMat (end,2);
VenusVXVec = VenusMat(end,3);
VenusVYVec = VenusMat(end,4);

EarthXVec = EarthMat (end,1);
EarthYVec = EarthMat (end,2);
EarthVXVec = EarthMat(end,3);
EarthVYVec = EarthMat(end,4);

MoonXVec = MoonMat (end,1);
MoonYVec = MoonMat (end,2);
MoonVXVec = MoonMat(end,3);
MoonVYVec =MoonMat(end,4);

MarsXVec = MarsMat (end,1);
MarsYVec = MarsMat (end,2);
MarsVXVec = MarsMat(end,3);
MarsVYVec = MarsMat(end,4);

JupiterXVec = JupiterMat (end,1);
JupiterYVec = JupiterMat (end,2);
JupiterVXVec = JupiterMat(end,3);
JupiterVYVec =JupiterMat(end,4);

SaturnXVec = SaturnMat (end,1);
SaturnYVec = SaturnMat (end,2);
SaturnVXVec = SaturnMat(end,3);
SaturnVYVec =SaturnMat(end,4);

UranusXVec = UranusMat (end,1);
UranusYVec = UranusMat (end,2);
UranusVXVec = UranusMat(end,3);
UranusVYVec =UranusMat(end,4);

NeptuneXVec = NeptuneMat (end,1);
NeptuneYVec = NeptuneMat (end,2);
NeptuneVXVec = NeptuneMat(end,3);
NeptuneVYVec =NeptuneMat(end,4);

SunVec=[SunXVec,SunYVec,SunVXVec,SunVYVec,mass(1),1];
MercuryVec = [MercuryXVec, MercuryYVec, MercuryVXVec, MercuryVYVec,mass(2),2];
VenusVec = [VenusXVec, VenusYVec, VenusVXVec, VenusVYVec,mass(3),3];
EarthVec = [EarthXVec, EarthYVec, EarthVXVec, EarthVYVec,mass(4),4];
MoonVec = [MoonXVec,MoonYVec,MoonVXVec,MoonVYVec,mass(10),10];
MarsVec = [MarsXVec, MarsYVec, MarsVXVec, MarsVYVec,mass(5),5];
JupiterVec = [JupiterXVec, JupiterYVec, JupiterVXVec, JupiterVYVec,mass(6),6];
SaturnVec = [SaturnXVec, SaturnYVec, SaturnVXVec, SaturnVYVec,mass(7),7];
UranusVec = [UranusXVec, UranusYVec,UranusVXVec, UranusVYVec,mass(8),8];
NeptuneVec = [NeptuneXVec, NeptuneYVec, NeptuneVXVec, NeptuneVYVec,mass(9),9];
PlanetVec=[SunVec(1),SunVec(2),SunVec(3),SunVec(4),SunVec(5),SunVec(6);MercuryVec(1),                MercuryVec(2), MercuryVec(3), MercuryVec(4),MercuryVec(5),MercuryVec(6);VenusVec(1),  VenusVec(2), VenusVec(3), VenusVec(4),VenusVec(5),VenusVec(6);EarthVec(1), EarthVec(2),   EarthVec(3),   EarthVec(4),EarthVec(5),EarthVec(6);MoonVec(1),MoonVec(2),MoonVec(3),MoonVec(4),MoonVec(5),MoonVec(6);MarsVec(1), MarsVec(2), MarsVec(3), MarsVec(4),MarsVec(5),MarsVec(6);JupiterVec(1),  JupiterVec(2), JupiterVec(3), JupiterVec(4),JupiterVec(5),JupiterVec(6);SaturnVec(1),  SaturnVec(2), SaturnVec(3), SaturnVec(4),SaturnVec(5),SaturnVec(6);UranusVec(1),  UranusVec(2),UranusVec(3), UranusVec(4),UranusVec(15),UranusVec(6);NeptuneVec(1),  NeptuneVec(2), NeptuneVec(3), NeptuneVec(4),NeptuneVec(5),NeptuneVec(6)];

plot (SunXVec,SunYVec,'.','Color','yellow');
hold on;
plot (MercuryXVec,MercuryYVec,'.','Color','green');
hold on;
plot (VenusXVec,VenusYVec,'.','Color','blue');
hold on;
plot (EarthXVec,EarthYVec, '.','Color', 'red');
hold on;
plot (MoonXVec,MoonYVec, '.','Color','black');
hold on;
plot (MarsXVec,MarsYVec, '.','Color','black');
hold on;
plot (JupiterXVec,JupiterYVec,'.','Color','green');
hold on;
plot (SaturnXVec,SaturnYVec, '.','Color','blue');
hold on;
plot (UranusXVec,UranusYVec, '.','Color','red');
hold on;
plot (NeptuneXVec,NeptuneYVec, '.','Color','blue');
hold on;
n=n+TimeStep;
end

function dYVec = GravityDE (TimeStep, YVec,PlanetVec)
load('solar_system_data.mat');
GravConst = 6.67259e-11;
Xi = YVec(1);
Yi = YVec(2);
VXi = YVec(3);
VYi = YVec(4);
Massi=YVec(5);
BodyName=YVec(6);

AccXtotal=0;
AccYtotal=0;
j=1;
while j<=10

Massj=PlanetVec(j,5);
Yj=PlanetVec(j,2);
Xj=PlanetVec(j,1);



RangeSq = (Xi-Xj).^2 + (Yi-Yj).^2;
if RangeSq==0
    AccMag=0;
    Theta = atan2(Yi-Yj,Xi-Xj);
    AccX = -AccMag .* cos (Theta);
    AccY = -AccMag .* sin (Theta);
    j=j+1;
    AccXtotal=AccXtotal+AccX;
    AccYtotal=AccYtotal+AccY;
else
    Theta = atan2(Yi-Yj,Xi-Xj);
    AccMag = (GravConst .* Massj ./ RangeSq);
    AccX = -AccMag .* cos (Theta);
    AccY = -AccMag .* sin (Theta);
    j=j+1;
    AccXtotal=AccXtotal+AccX;
    AccYtotal=AccYtotal+AccY;
    VXi=VXi+AccXtotal.*TimeStep;
    VYi=VYi+AccYtotal.*TimeStep;
end

dYVec = [VXi; VYi; AccXtotal; AccYtotal;Massi;BodyName];

end
```

Thanks!!

Comment: You do realize that you're not actually taking the effects of the other planets into account? The way you're doing it, each call to `ode45` only considers 1 planet...which renders those integrations into a complicated way to discover Keplerian motion :)

Comment: Also, taking the mass of a celestial body and then multiplying it by Newton's *G* to get *GM* is mortal sin. *G* is the *least* precisely known physical constant! What you measure when you do orbital analysis (that's how all the masses of all the planets are measured) is the product *GM* (which is usually called *μ*, the [standard gravitational parameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravitational_parameter)). The accuracy with which the *μ*'s of all the planets are known, are orders of magnitude better than their masses (which are simply calcualated as *μ/G*).

Comment: OK, I see now where you want to go. That approach is not correct. I have to go to work now, but I'll have an answer for you in a few hours.

Answer (score 5):

OK, here we go. It's going to be a ***LONG*** answer, and it will probably be over-complete, but I think it'll be valuable also for future visitors.

The force on a celestial body of mass *M* due to another celestial body of mass *m* equals

*F = -GMm / r²*

where *r* is the distance between the two bodies. That is how we all learn Newton's equation in high school (I hope, anyway...). The basic equation above is somewhat flawed, for reasons I indicated in my comment above. Also, it is incomplete in the context of more-than-two celestial bodies.

First, *GM* is replaced by something that can actually be measured, *μ* -- a body's [standard gravitational parameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravitational_parameter). Second, calculations need to be easy to do in an arbitrary coordinate system. Third, the *direction* of the force is not included in the equation above. Fourth, the *acceleration* of a celestial body is usually what matters, not the force.

All this can be included by re-phrasing the equation as

**r̈**<sub>i</sub> = Σ<sub>j≠i</sub> *μ*<sub>j</sub> **r**<sub>ij</sub> / |**r<sub>ij</sub>**|³

where boldface letters indicate vectors, **r** is a position vector w.r.t. some arbitrary coordinate system, **r**<sub>ij</sub> = **r**<sub>i</sub> - **r**<sub>j</sub> is the vector from body *i* to body *j*, and the double-dots are Newton's double-fluxions (equal to Leibniz' d²/dt²).

In words: the instantaneous directed acceleration of body *i* due to the gravitational effects of all other bodies *j*, is the summation of the gravitational parameters *μ*<sub>j</sub>, divided by the squared distance between body *i* and *j*, and multiplied by the vector between the two bodies scaled to unity, over all other bodies *j* in the system (you see why we invented Mathematical notation? :)

This equation describes a system of *j* second-order differential equations, which cannot be solved analytically (in an easily computable, closed form anyway) and must therefore be solved numerically. Matlab's `ode45` can do that, although its accuracy leaves something to be desired if you want to simulate the planet's orbits for several dozens of years or more (especially mercury's orbit is notoriously difficult to compute accurately numerically).

Anyway, you solve this with `ode45` as follows. Define

**y**<sub>0</sub> = [**r**<sub>1</sub> **ṙ**<sub>1</sub> **r**<sub>2</sub> **ṙ**<sub>2</sub> ... **r**<sub>j</sub> **ṙ**<sub>j</sub> ]<sup>T</sup>

which is the collection of initial state vectors of all *j* bodies. In code (independent of input sizes):

```
y0 = [xposition(:) yposition(:) vx(:) vy(:)].';  
y0 = y0(:);
```

Note that you do *not* need to give all the state vectors individual names. This I also strongly discourage; how would you go about integrating the asteroid belt? Would you really give ~500.000 variable names to all the individual state vectors? No--use Matlab's vector/matrix nature to your advantage.

You can probably prevent the mess above by defining your `xposition` and `yposition` (and speeds) not separately, but together in a single vector.

The `ode45` integrator works by computing

**ẏ** = [**ṙ**<sub>1</sub> **r̈**<sub>1</sub> **ṙ**<sub>2</sub> **r̈**<sub>2</sub> ... **ṙ**<sub>j</sub> **r̈**<sub>j</sub> ]<sup>T</sup>

from an input **y** at each iteration. It is here that the modified Newton's equation above comes into play; to compute the double-fluxions **r̈**<sub>j</sub>. In code:

```
% collect data     
r = [y(1:4:end) y(2:4:end)];  % X/Y positions
V = [y(3:4:end) y(4:4:end)];  % Vx/Vy speeds

% initialize output
ydotdot = zeros(size(y));
ydotdot(1:4:end) = V(:,1);  % we already know the first half;
ydotdot(2:4:end) = V(:,2);  % it's simply equal to the speeds

% Compute all accelerations. 
% This is where ALL the computational burden is -- when optimizing 
% for speed, this is where to start!
sz   = size(r,1);
accx = zeros(sz);
accy = zeros(sz);
for ii = 1:sz
    ri = r(ii,:);
    for jj = ii+1:sz
        rij = ri - r(jj,:);
        sc  = (rij*rij.')^(-3/2);
        accx(jj,ii) = rij(1) * sc;
        accy(jj,ii) = rij(2) * sc;
    end
end

accx = bsxfun(@times, -mu(:), accx-accx.');
accy = bsxfun(@times, -mu(:), accy-accy.');

% insert accelerations
ydotdot(3:4:end) = sum(accx);
ydotdot(4:4:end) = sum(accy);
```

The way you were doing it was to compute the double-fluxion of the position of the planet, while the other planets were in their *initial* positions; you wanted to pass `PlanetVec`, the collection of initial statevectors (that I've called **y**<sub>0</sub>) into `GravityDE`, and compute distances and accelerations of the planet w.r.t. that vector.

This is or course incorrect -- this will only move one planet, while keeping the other planets still. That's not how the Solar system works :p Now you might argue that it doesn't matter much, since the planets move so slowly, but that is true only for the outer planets; Mercury's influence on Venus' orbit for example is grossly miscalculated that way.

Now you know the general principles. ***DISCLAIMER***: I've written this all from memory without much checking, so I might have missed a minus sign here and there. I think it's a good exercise for you to understand and check everything I did here.

Now, a complete, functional, copy-pastable summary:

```
function Gravity1

    % NOTE: 'clear' has no meaning at the start of a function; a function
    % has its own variable space, meaning it is empty to begin with.

    % NOTE: this assumes you put have all the planetary mu's inside this datafile
    load('solar_system_data.mat');

    % NOTE: ode45 chooses its own time steps; its an adaptive method.
    % Passing it custom time steps is hopelessly inefficient.
    t0   = 0;
    tend = 24 * 3600 * 100;

    % re-format initial vectors
    y0 = [xposition(:) yposition(:) vx(:) vy(:)].';  
    y0 = y0(:);

    % perform integration 
    [t y] = ode45(@d2ydt2, [t0 tend], y0);

    % and do plot
    h = figure; hold on % NOTE: only a single 'hold on' is needed to turn it on :) 
    plot(y(:,1),y(:,2), 'y.');    % Sun
    plot(y(:,1),y(:,2), 'g.');    % Mercury
    plot(y(:,1),y(:,2), 'b.');    % Venus
    plot(y(:,1),y(:,2), 'r.');    % Earth
    plot(y(:,1),y(:,2), 'k.');    % Mars
    plot(y(:,1),y(:,2), 'g.');    % Jupiter
    plot(y(:,1),y(:,2), 'b.');    % Saturn
    plot(y(:,1),y(:,2), 'r.');    % Uranus
    plot(y(:,1),y(:,2), 'b.');    % Neptune


    % It's easiest to put the differential equation in a nested function    
    function ydotdot = d2ydt2(~,y)

        % rename data     
        r = [y(1:4:end) y(2:4:end)];  % X/Y positions
        V = [y(3:4:end) y(4:4:end)];  % Vx/Vy speeds

        % initialize output
        ydotdot = zeros(size(y));
        ydotdot(1:4:end) = V(:,1);  % we already know the first half;
        ydotdot(2:4:end) = V(:,2);  % it's simply equal to the speeds

        % Compute all accelerations. 
        % This is where ALL the computational burden is -- when optimizing 
        % for speed, this is where to start!
        sz   = size(r,1);
        accx = zeros(sz);
        accy = zeros(sz);
        for ii = 1:sz
            ri = r(ii,:);
            for jj = ii+1:sz
                rij = ri - r(jj,:);
                sc  = (rij*rij.')^(-3/2);
                accx(jj,ii) = rij(1) * sc;
                accy(jj,ii) = rij(2) * sc;
            end
        end

        accx = bsxfun(@times, -mu(:), accx-accx.');
        accy = bsxfun(@times, -mu(:), accy-accy.');

        % insert accelerations
        ydotdot(3:4:end) = sum(accx);
        ydotdot(4:4:end) = sum(accy);

    end

end
```

Note that I have not even looked at why your original function failed to run. I bet that once you get this running, it doesn't really matter anymore.

Comment: +1: you're trying way too hard, making the rest of us look like a bunch of idle slackers.

Comment: @HighPerormanceMark: Well, this is actually what I studied :) I spent years with this stuff, I can't help myself :p

Answer (score 0):

Without `solar_system_data.mat`, it's hard to debug your code, but the problem is that your are not passing `PlanetVec` to your function

If my memory serves me well, you should try

```
[TimeVec, SunMat] = ode45(@(t,y)GravityDE(t,y,PlanetVec), TimeStepMin, SunVec);
```

Please read about [parameterizing functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html)

Comment: Unfortunately using that approach gets the error too many input arguments??   Also, solar_system_data.mat contains six simple vectors of the masses, initial velocities(x and y), initial positions(x and y) and the names of the planets(also earth's moon).

Comment: Again, since I can't run you're code, I can't tell you what's wrong. My syntax is correct. I would also completely rewrite your code to make better use of how Matlab handles matrices.